# MVC saving a list to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am trying to save a list of emails to my database but I am having trouble getting the list to save.

This is the List in the model:

```
[Display(Name = "Mailing List")]
public List<string> MailingList { get; set; }
```

This is the controller method where I am trying to add a new string email to the list and save it to the database

```
public ActionResult VenueMailingList(int id)
{
    //Get UserID and Email
    string UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    string email = User.Identity.Name;

    //Check if the user is logged in
    if (UserId != null)
    {
        ViewBag.LoggedIn = true;

        //Add the users email to this venues email mailing list
        Venue venue = db.Venues.Find(id);

        //If list is null, initlise it
        if (venue.MailingList == null)
        {
            venue.MailingList = new List<string>();
        }

        venue.MailingList.Add(email);

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: You have not provided the details of the actual problem. Are you getting an error at some point when you run this? If so, can you add that information to the question?

Comment: The problem is that the list is not saving to the database

Comment: use this under the Required in your model class `[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]` Also can I suggest since you are using EF and obviously have the AspNetUsers login tables, just use a trigger to automatically update your MailingList table when someone new registers (adding a row into AspNetUsers table)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the database changes inside of your DbContext, so that EntityFramework tracks the change and saves those changes into your DB. You need code like the following:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
     Venue venue = context.Venues.Find(id);

     //If list is null, initlise it
     if (venue.MailingList == null)
     {
          venue.MailingList = new List<string>();
     }

     venue.MailingList.Add(email);

     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The following link has a great tutorial of how to use EntityFramework: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/add-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (venue.MailingList == null)
{
          venue.MailingList = new List<string>();
}

venue.MailingList.Add(email);
venue.MailingList.Entry(email).State = EntityState.Added; // you need to add this statement

db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

please use addrange method.

```
db.YourTable.AddRange(YourList)
db.SaveChanges();
```